# Block page on hit enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, block

I am using jquery block page and when I click into the specified div it is worjing.
I want when I click enter into #ui-id-1 to call the function

```
$(function ($) {
    // wire up all the demo code
    $('.submit, #menu, #ui-id-1').each(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.submit, #menu, #ui-id-1').click(function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    css: {
                        border: 'none',
                        padding: '10px',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                        backgroundImage: 'url(/images/loader2.gif)',
                        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                        backgroundPosition: '10px',
                        marginTop: '20px',
                        marginBottom: '20px',
                            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                        opacity: .7,
                        color: '#000'
                    }
                });
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 15000);
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: What kind of element is `#ui-id-` ? If it's an `:input` element, just add a `keyup` handler. (The `which` keycode you want is `13`) If not, you'll need to add a `keyup` handler on the `document` element, passing `true` to the `useCapture` parameter, and then try to determine if you where "focused" on the appropriate element at the time (i.e: was it visible to the user, not the normal meaning of 'focus' in HTML).

Comment: This is some strange code, why the double document ready (the second one being in a `each` loop. And you don't need a loop to assign the click handler to all 3 ids.

Comment: the #ui-id is an input element
I use code
$('#ui-id-1').(event.keyCode==13)(function() {.....
but is not working